# How to Select Top N record with N count as parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to have a simple JPA method in repository interface that can define N as parameter:

```
 List<Messages> findTopCountByStatusEquals(int count, String status);
```

That is not working, I can only use predefined Top count:

```
List<Messages> findTop10ByStatusEquals(String status);
```

Is it possible to make Top count as runtime parameter for this?

Comment: You can use a pageable request for that

Answer (score 1):

As per [Spring Data JPA doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result), its is not possible to do as your described, BUT you can use [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) as a parameter instead of an int to achieve your result

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository{
     List<Messages> findByStatusEquals(Pageable pageable, String status);
}
```

And then in your service:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public Page<Messages> findByStatusEquals(String status) {
    Pageable pageRequest = createPageRequest()
    return this.messagesRepository.findByStatusEquals(pageRequest, searchResultPage);
}

private Pageable createPageRequest() {
    return new PageRequest(0, 10);
}
```

You can of course also apply sorting if needed :

```
private Pageable createPageRequest() {
    return new PageRequest(0, 
        10, 
        new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "messageBody")
                .and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "someOtherField"));
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this better way in you repository interface if you use java8.

```
List<Messages> findByStatus(String status, Pageable pageable);

default List<Messages> findTopCountByStatusEquals(int count, String status) {
  return findByStatus(status, PageRequest.of(0, count));
}
```

This use java8 default method to perfectly match what you want.